# How do I use a window as splash screen in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, splash-screen

I would like to use a regular window for splash screen, so no PNG splash screen but a normal window where I can add some bitmaps on.

What is the best way: to keep in app.xaml the loading of the main screen and put the splash screen in the constructor or somewhere in an event handler?

The splash scren itself is quite easy, just has some labels, a link, a few images and just waits a few seconds before closing, no actions to be done while waiting.

Comment: Ironically, considering all the people who snarkily recommend WPF for problems experienced by WinForms developers, this is extremely easy to do in WinForms...

Comment: google: "wpf splash screen", 2nd result: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: Don't be quite so earnest. That implementation is crap.

Comment: A lot of CodeProject stuff is flakey, scary stuff..

Comment: @DavidAnderson & Jon: That is not the case with this project. I used the same link to create my WPF app splash screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for a splash screen, it is very important to make use of the [functionality introduced in .NET 3.5 for this purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx). If you simply use a vanilla `Window` it can take quite some time for the WPF stack to initialize, and in the interim the user will not be seeing any feedback for their "launch the app" action.

Of course this does not satisfy the requirements of the question ("use a regular window"), but if it's not acceptable I would recommend using an different technology than WPF entirely because of the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Agreed, using a WPF window as a splash screen kind of defeats the point (especially when the splash screen is just frill, and theres nothing actually going on). Using a WinForm would be fine since initialization time is quick, but you should just use the Splash Screen build action anyway.

Comment: I decided to use my own regular window after all because I need specific controls on it, but accepted this answer because it is the prefered way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I have myself designed my WPF app dynamic splash screen in which there was an animation, dynamic software Number which changed for each and every software, a label which was updated every 1/2 ms to show some random filename in the sofware directory.

To be frank i used this link to create mine

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF

There are other links which i can provide you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116875/WPF-Loading-Splash-Screen
http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/A-better-WPF-splash-screen.aspx